# Generate core dump for a process run by sudo

Tags: linux, root, sudo, dump, ulimit

To my `/etc/security/limits.conf` I add the following lines and rebooted:

```
root            soft    core            unlimited
*               soft    core            unlimited
```

Now core dumps are generated under my user and under `sudo su`. And in both cases `ulimit -a` shows me the desired:

```
core file size              (blocks, -c) unlimited
```

But when under my user I run `sudo bash -c "ulimit -a"` I get:

```
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0
```

and core dumps for processes run with `sudo` and destroyed e.g. by SIGSEGV are not generated at `/var/lib/apport/coredump/`. This command also does not help: `sudo bash -c "ulimit -c unlimited"`.

What can be done? Could you, please explain, why the core dump limit for sudo is different than that of root? I expected that when I run `sudo bash -c "ulimit -a"` I would  get values for root. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
# cat  /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers
Defaults rlimit_core=default
```

The answer was found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1733614/how-to-configure-core-dumps-ulimit-c-from-within-sudo-within-docker

The explanation:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/sudoers.5.html :

> Resource limits
> ...  The one exception to this is the core dump file size,
> which is set by sudoers to 0 by default.  Disabling core dumps by default makes it possible
> to avoid potential security problems where the core file is treated as trusted input.

Also, note that it's crucial to make `kill -11 $mypid`, where the pid is that of `./myapp`, rather than its parent process `sudo ./myapp`. Note: 11 is SIGSEGV.